# How to search for comments ("<!-- -->") using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like to remove those tags with their content from source HTML.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When searching you basically use `Elements.select(selector)` where `selector` is defined by [this API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). However comments are not elements technically, so you may be confused here, still they are nodes identified by the node name `#comment`.

Let's see how that might work:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;

public class RemoveComments {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String h = "<html><head></head><body>" +
          "<div><!-- foo --><p>bar<!-- baz --></div><!--qux--></body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(h);
        removeComments(doc);
        doc.html(System.out);
    }

    private static void removeComments(Node node) {
        for (int i = 0; i < node.childNodeSize();) {
            Node child = node.childNode(i);
            if (child.nodeName().equals("#comment"))
                child.remove();
            else {
                removeComments(child);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: If you can get a 6 year old version of Jsoup, it worked back then. Otherwise, if the api is updated, I welcome fixes to update this example. It looks like the childNodes list<node> was made unmodifiable in some version.

Comment: Using JSoup 1.11.3 and Groovy... the only change I needed to make to get it to work was to change childNodesSize() to childNodeSize().

Comment: @RobertHanson Thanks, that might have been a transcription error.

Comment: nice but be aware what docs says about `nodeName` method:

***
Get the node name of this node. Use for **debugging purposes** and not logic switching (for that, use instanceof)
***

So you should rather use `Comment.class.isInstance(child)`.

Answer (score 3):

With JSoup 1.11+ (possibly older version) you can apply a filter:

```java
private void removeComments(Element article) {
    article.filter(new NodeFilter() {
        @Override
        public FilterResult tail(Node node, int depth) {
            if (node instanceof Comment) {
                return FilterResult.REMOVE;
            }
            return FilterResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FilterResult head(Node node, int depth) {
            if (node instanceof Comment) {
                return FilterResult.REMOVE;
            }
            return FilterResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

reference @dlamblin https://stackoverflow.com/a/7541875/4712855 this code get comment html

```
public static void getHtmlComments(Node node) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node.childNodeSize();i++) {
        Node child = node.childNode(i);
        if (child.nodeName().equals("#comment")) {
            Comment comment = (Comment) child;
            child.after(comment.getData());
            child.remove();
        }
        else {
            getHtmlComments(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from @dlamblin a Java 8 functional approach (sorry but this seems to be a littler simpler and cleaner than the aswer from @Feuerrabe)

```
private void removeComments(Node node) {
    node.childNodes().stream().filter(n -> "#comment".equals(n.nodeName())).forEach(Node::remove);
    node.childNodes().forEach(this::removeComments);
}
```

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
removeComments(doc);
// ...
```

Comment: elegant and efficient

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of the first example using a functional programming approach. The easiest way to find all comments, which are immediate children of the current node is to use `.filter()` on a stream of `.childNodes()`

```
public void removeComments(Element e) {
    e.childNodes().stream()
        .filter(n -> n.nodeName().equals("#comment")).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEach(n -> n.remove());
    e.children().forEach(elem -> removeComments(elem));
}
```

Full example:

```
package demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
public class Demo {

public static void removeComments(Element e) {
    e.childNodes().stream()
        .filter(n -> n.nodeName().equals("#comment")).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEach(n -> n.remove());
    e.children().forEach(elem -> removeComments(elem));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/"), 500);

    // do not try this with JDK < 8
    String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(userHome + File.separator + "before.html"));
    out.print(doc.outerHtml());
    out.close();

    removeComments(doc);
    out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(userHome + File.separator + "after.html"));
    out.print(doc.outerHtml());
    out.close();
}
```

}