# ConcurrentModificationException in Java Stream but not in for loop with counter

Tags: java-8, jsoup

I am removing comment nodes with jsoup and found something I do not understand.
This code works:
**Example 1:**

```
private static void removeComments(Node node) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node.childNodes().size();) {
        Node child = node.childNode(i);
        if (child.nodeName().equals("#comment"))
            child.remove();
        else {
            removeComments(child);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

But this code throws an ConcurrentModificationException:
**Example 2**

```
private static void removeComments(Node node) {
    node.childNodes()
            .forEach(n -> {
                if (n.nodeName().equals("#comment")) {
                    n.remove();
                } else {
                    removeComments(n);
                }
            });
}
```

I try to write short, easy to understand code, ternary operator not supporting two void returns already destroyed my "oneline" approach. What limitation did I hit with that strange behaviour?

Comment: just for reference: Example 1 is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541843/how-to-search-for-comments-using-jsoup

Comment: Note that you are not using "Java Stream" here. The `Iterable.forEach` method is not part of Stream API.

Comment: You can implement it as two-pass operation: `private static void removeComments(Node node) {
    node.childNodes().removeIf(n -> n.nodeName().equals("#comment")); node.childNodes().forEach(n -> removeComments(n)); }`. In this case you can replace the lambda expression `n -> removeComments(n)` with a method reference of the `SurroundingClass::removeComments` form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) occurs when you modify the list (by adding or removing elements) while traversing a list with an Iterator.

You can't modify a List in a for/each loop, which is syntactic sugar around the Iterator as an implementation detail. You can only safely call `.remove()` when using the Iterator **directly**.

Calling `.remove()` inside the for/each loop modifies the contents, and the Iterator that is used behind the scenes sees this and throws this exception.

Read about [How to Avoid ConcurrentModificationException when using an Iterator](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html#ixzz1plFiXfzz).

Comment: I remember that limitation. But in the first example there is a for loop used as well. It doesn't throw any exception and I don't see the difference.

Comment: You are not using an iterator in the first example, that's the difference.

Comment: To be more precise, the first example is not even iterating over the list. It invokes `childNodes()` (in each iteration) only to (re)query the size, but the elements are fetched via `childNode(int)`, invoked on the node, so it’s iterating over child nodes via the `Node`’s API, though this might be semantically equivalent, depending on how `Node` is implemented, but each API has it’s own requirements regarding the state (consistency) between the invocations…